# How to reset the time to zero using time.h for a video game timer?

Tags: time, timer

I'm programming a graphics engine. I want to have a control on my frame rate and all task requiring time managing. Currently, my timer is able to get the current time (initialized at the beginning of the program execution) using clock() method and compute the elapse time. But I would like to reset the time to zero and it seems to be not possible with time.h.
Does anyone know a library which do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write your own timer class for that. When starting the timer, you store the current time, when asking the timer how much time has passed you query the current time again, and compare it to the starting time. You can reset the timer by overwriting the starting time with the current time.

You also probably don't want to use clock(), since it only measures processor time as opposed to wall clock time. If the processor is busy with another task (e.g. the idle task) your timing will be off. Note that C++ **sucks very very much** when it comes to timers. You'll have to use an OS specific function, e.g. `QueryPerformanceCounter` on Windows.

Oh right, if you use C++11 and are willing and able to endure horrible syntax you can try [chrono](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/).

Comment: "*Note that C++ sucks very very much when it comes to timers.*" [*cough*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Comment: Yea I just remembered.

Answer (score 0):

Have you by chance checked out the boost cpu timers?(http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html)

Its pretty comprehensive it what it can do, might be a good alternative to using clock.

A simple example includes putting `boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;` in your scoped code and when `t` goes out of scope it will capture the time for you.

Answer (score 0):

The boost timer class suits for you.

Here is the boost timer class.

```
class timer
{
 public:
  timer() { _start_time = std::clock(); } // postcondition: elapsed()==0
  // reset the timer
  void   restart() { _start_time = std::clock(); } // post: elapsed()==0
  double elapsed() const                  // return elapsed time in seconds
    { return  double(std::clock() - _start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; }

  double elapsed_max() const   // return estimated maximum value for elapsed()
  // Portability warning: elapsed_max() may return too high a value on systems
  // where std::clock_t overflows or resets at surprising values.
  {
    return (double((std::numeric_limits<std::clock_t>::max)())
       - double(_start_time)) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC); 
  }

  double elapsed_min() const            // return minimum value for elapsed()
   { return double(1)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC); }

 private:
  std::clock_t _start_time;
}; // timer
```

**demo**:

```
#include <boost/timer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    timer t;
    cout << "max timespan:" << t.elapsed_max() << "s" << endl;
    cout << "min timespan:" << t.elapsed_min() << "s" << endl;

    // consume time
    for ( long i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i )
        std::sqrt(123.456L);

    cout << "now time elapsed:" << t.elapsed() << "s" << endl;

    // reset timer
    t.restart();
    // consume time
    for ( long i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i )
        std::sqrt(123.456L);

    cout << "now time elapsed:" << t.elapsed() << "s" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**compile demo**
`g++ demo.c -o demo -lm`